# What is the correct usage of multiple useRef()`s to hide a <div /> when a button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

In my application I have currently two buttons in two different components, which when clicked show another `<div>` of their respective parent component. When clicked outside of said `<div>` the `<div>` should not be displayed. For better illustration see attached screenshot (the buttons are marked in red): [image: Screenshot of application]

Right now I have the problem that the divs are not hided when clicked on one of the other buttons of components where I implemented `useRef()` to check if a click occurred outside of said component. That is because currently I call `event.stopPropagation()` in the respective `onClick()` functions of said buttons.

See 'input' component:

```js
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import EmptyPromptIcon from "./emptyPromptIcon";
import SearchOptionsIcon from "./searchOptionsIcon";

export default function SearchBar() {
    const router = useRouter();
    const [input, setInput] = useState({ keyword: "", matchType: "exact" });
    const [displayOptions, setDisplayOptions] = useState(false);
    const wrapperRef = useRef();

    useEffect(() => {
        function hideDropdown(event) {
            if (
                wrapperRef.current &&
                !wrapperRef.current.contains(event.target)
            ) {
                wrapperRef.current.style.visibility = "hidden";
                setDisplayOptions(false);
            }
        }
        document.addEventListener("click", hideDropdown);
        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener("click", hideDropdown);
        };
    }, [wrapperRef]);

    const handleOnChange = (event) => {
        setInput((prevInput) => ({
            ...prevInput,
            keyword: event.target.value,
        }));
    };

    const handleEmptyPrompt = () => {
        document.getElementById("search-input").focus();
        document.getElementById("empty-prompt-icon").classList.add("hover");
        input && setInput("");
    };

    const handleSearchOptions = (event) => {
        event.stopPropagation()
        if (!displayOptions) {
            wrapperRef.current.style.visibility = "visible";
            setDisplayOptions(true);
        } else {
            wrapperRef.current.style.visibility = "hidden";
            setDisplayOptions(false);
        }
    };

    const handleMatchTypeClick = (event) => {
        setInput((prevInput) => ({
            ...prevInput,
            matchType: event.target.value,
        }));
    };

    const handleOnSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        router.push({
            pathname: `/search/${input.keyword}`,
        });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        const input = document.getElementById("search-input");
        const inputImage = document.getElementById("empty-prompt-icon");

        function addHover() {
            input === document.activeElement &&
                inputImage.classList.add("hover");
        }
        function removeHover() {
            inputImage.classList.remove("hover");
        }
        inputImage.addEventListener("mouseenter", addHover);
        inputImage.addEventListener("mouseleave", removeHover);
    });

    return (
        <div id="search-bar-wrapper">
            <form onSubmit={(event) => handleOnSubmit(event)}>
                <input
                    id="search-input"
                    maxLength={"40"}
                    autoComplete="off"
                    autoCorrect="off"
                    onChange={(event) => handleOnChange(event)}
                    placeholder={
                        "Insert a word to look for in Korean or English"
                    }
                    value={input.keyword}
                ></input>
                <button
                    type="reset"
                    id="empty-prompt-button"
                    onClick={() => handleEmptyPrompt()}
                >
                    <EmptyPromptIcon />
                </button>
                <button
                    type="button"
                    id="search-options-button"
                    onClick={(event) => handleSearchOptions(event)}
                >
                    <SearchOptionsIcon />
                </button>
                <div ref={wrapperRef} id="search-options-wrapper">
                    <div>Match-Type:</div>
                    <div id="search-option-match-types">
                        <label
                            htmlFor="match-type-exact"
                            className="match-type"
                            onClick={(event) => handleMatchTypeClick(event)}
                        >
                            <input
                                name="search-match-type"
                                id="match-type-exact"
                                type="radio"
                                value="exact"
                            />
                            <span className="checkmark"></span>
                            <span>Exact</span>
                        </label>
                        <label
                            htmlFor="match-type-fuzzy"
                            className="match-type"
                            onClick={(event) => handleMatchTypeClick(event)}
                        >
                            <input
                                name="search-match-type"
                                id="match-type-fuzzy"
                                type="radio"
                                value="fuzzy"
                            />
                            <span className="checkmark"></span>
                            <span>Fuzzy</span>
                        </label>
                        <label
                            htmlFor="match-type-include"
                            className="match-type"
                            onClick={(event) => handleMatchTypeClick(event)}
                        >
                            <input
                                name="search-match-type"
                                id="match-type-include"
                                type="radio"
                                value="include"
                            />
                            <span className="checkmark"></span>
                            <span>Include</span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
```

See the 'sort' component:

```js
import SortIcon from "./sortIcon";

import { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function SortDropdown({ order, setOrder }) {
    const [display, setDisplay] = useState(false);
    const wrapperRef = useRef(null);

    const handleToggleSort = (event) => {
        event.stopPropagation();
        if (!display) {
            wrapperRef.current.style.visibility = "visible";
            setDisplay(true);
        } else {
            wrapperRef.current.style.visibility = "hidden";
            setDisplay(false);
        }
    };

    const handleOnClickSort = (option) => {
        order !== option && setOrder(option);
        wrapperRef.current.style.visibility = "hidden";
        setDisplay(false);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        function hideDropdown(event) {
            if (
                wrapperRef.current &&
                !wrapperRef.current.contains(event.target)
            ) {
                wrapperRef.current.style.visibility = "hidden";
                setDisplay(false);
            }
        }
        document.addEventListener("click", hideDropdown);
        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener("click", hideDropdown);
        };
    }, [wrapperRef, display]);

    return (
        <div className="sort-dropdown-container">
            <button
                type="button"
                id="sort-results-button"
                onClick={(event) => handleToggleSort(event)}
            >
                <SortIcon />
            </button>
            <div ref={wrapperRef} className="sort-options">
                <ul>
                    <li onClick={() => handleOnClickSort("Frequency")}>
                        Sort by: Frequency
                    </li>
                    <li onClick={() => handleOnClickSort("Alpha")}>
                        Sort by: Name
                    </li>
                    <li onClick={() => handleOnClickSort("Accuracy")}>
                        Sort by: Accuracy
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Is `hideDropdown` handler being executed on click? And if does, did you manage to enter inside handler to check whether code for hiding actually executes(updates div through ref)?

Comment: ```hideDropdown``` is executed on every update of either ```wrapperRef``` or ```display```.

Comment: But it should be executed only on click, right? Not on update of ref or inner state? I wanted to know if you debugged on-click event, does it enters inside hideDropdown when you click outside and does it end up on these two lines of code where you change style and doing setDisplay(false)

Comment: I attached a eventListener on the document level. That's why I needed to wrap it into a ```useEffect()```

Comment: I understand that part, I just wanted to know did you put debugger, for example on line where you are doing `wrapperRef.current.style.visibility = "hidden";` and while debugging does your code hit that line where you update div and inner state? And one more thing I would like to check is to be sure that you are not having any custom style for class name `sort-options` and for id `search-options-wrapper` since that styling can make conflict with style you are trying to apply programmatically inside event handler.

Comment: I am sorry I can't really follow you regarding your first questions. Regarding your second question: there are no custom styles involved besides styling in the css file itself.